# How to make my HTML table stay at the same place while resizing the browser window?

Tags: html, css

How do I make my table stay at same position when I resize my browser window?

I am using css:

```
#table{

    top: 78px;
    right: 850px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Put the table inside a div

Comment: Stay in the same place relative to what? The top-right corner of your browser corner? A parent element? Your bedroom wall? Please read here to see how to create a [MCVE]. Thanks.

Comment: There's not really enough info here to give a complete answer. Are you trying to center it? You could try flex-box, or position: relative; margin: auto;, or you could use text-align center. It really depend on what you are trying to do.

Comment: your question doesn't have enough information please look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Answer (score 0):

there isn't enough information but there's something that you *might* not realized you are doing wrong.

If you are using `#<name>` in css you need to add `id=<name>` to the html tag as an attribute.

If you want all table to use that CSS, you need to remove the `#`